# Php website and database design

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was designing a php website which can login with different limit such as teacher and student.
I'm using XAMPP server and phpMyAdmin to create the database and it was success to connect to database already.

I suppose to create "student site" and "teacher site" , when user login, system can identify the user type and go to `"student site"` or `"teacher site"`.
It is because I suppose that "teacher site" has admin right to config student's work and "student page" is used to upload file to teacher.

How should I design my database? Should I create two database which is `"student"` and `"teacher"` or I should create one database which is `" member"` and add a category to identify teacher/student

Comment: I think this Question is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MartinSchneider - this would be much too broad to be asked on Programmers.  Please don't recommend other SE sites until you become familiar with the quality guidelines of that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `user_group` table that will store type of users. In your case there can be 3 users:

1. Super Admin - There will be only one user with this group having full rights of both teacher and student
2. Teacher - Group for teachers
3. Student - Group for students

Then create `users` table with basic information like Name, Email, Password, etc and an identifier to `user_group` which will identify whether the user is Super Admin / Teacher / Student.

Based on this group identifier in `users` table, you can decide in PHP code which site should be displayed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

no need 2 table, you can use members , that have column `type` , then in your programming , you can tell which type can see which part.

///EDIT:

in the other hand , you can create table names `homework` , that have columns like : `fromusert, tomaster,file,date`
then you can manage your requests , for sending homework to masters.

Answer (score 0):

if your login page the same for both you can make one table member and after login process you can get the category of the user and you must check the category with login credentials every request to your website pages because student can see different pages which teacher can see. in this case the username can't be repeated for student and teacher.

if you will give privileges for students or teacher say teacher1 can see and teacher2 can't see and in the same time student doesn't have these privileges, so in this case you should make different tables. in this case you should make different login pages or set category dropdown where the login user is teacher or student to make your authenticate by user selection.

conclusion, your requirements will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create different tables.The reason is students and teachers are different "entitites"..Defining two different entities provides you advantages in many ways..https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

For the the login use case it may seems logical to have one table..But requirements changes during development so use cases changes too..

The good thing about having two entities(student and teacher)..You can still have a member entity with a "is-a relationship"..

[image]

http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~ptw/teaching/DBM/er.pdf

If you are confused the term of "entity"..It is a single set of information..In your case Teachers is the table name..And the teacher represents a single teacher..